# Checkbox not working with materializecss - HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox, materialize

I can't seem to get checkbox to work whilst using the materializecss, as anyone else came cross this issue and managed to fix it?

The library I am using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
```

Checkbox without library - https://jsfiddle.net/d2yk4sbv/2/

```
     <div><label> <input type=checkbox> label 1 </label></div>
```

Checkbox with library - https://jsfiddle.net/d2yk4sbv/

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
            <div><label> <input type=checkbox> label 1 </label></div>
```

The checkbox seems to be working fine without the library but the problem is, my application depends on using the materializecss so I can't afford to not use it :(

Link to the materializecss website - http://materializecss.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be work. It seems like you need to put a relation between the label and the input check. Why don't you try in this way

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <label for="check">label 1</label>
</div>
```

http://materializecss.com/forms.html#checkbox

Comment: for materialize 1.0 [see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51006702/2581562)

Comment: none of the options work with materialize.css 1.0.0, my checkbox is inside a datatable but the opacity is always 0 and even if i change it so I can see the checkbox I cannot click on it to change the value. really weird

Answer (score 20):

In v1.0.0, checkbox inside label tag with text wrapped around span will only work.

```
   <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>Red</span>
   </label>
```

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1376

```html
 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
    
   Checkbox:  <br/>
   
   <label>
           <input type="checkbox" />
           <span></span>
      </label>
```

Comment: Good answer for those on 1.0.0 & up. The structure changed since 0.100.

Comment: The OP question was about version 0.100.2

Answer (score 8):

Regular HTML5 checkbox will not showing with materialcss loaded.

this is regular html5 check box.

```
     <input type="checkbox" name="nameOfChoice" value="1" checked>
```

As to today 2018, with 1.0, all above answer does not work any more, except this one.

You must follow the label, input, span structure to be work!

credit to @SmartManoj

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>Red</span>
</label>
```

https://materializecss.com/checkboxes.html

Answer (score 1):

it's not working because you have the wrong structure, put the `checkbox` next to the `label` and not inside it, and wrap both of them in a `p`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="test" checked="checked" />
  <label for="test">Hello</label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

**2019 - Version 1.0**

I like the concision of Materialize, but it got problems.

Trying to pass checkbox through Ajax.

```
if(state.success === true) {
                        tbody.append('<tr><th scope="row" style="background-color:' + state['color'] + 
                            '"><label><input type="checkbox" /><span>Red</span></label></th><td>' + state['date'] +
                            '</td><td>' + state['priority'] + '</td><td>' + state['name'] + 
                            '</td><td>' + state['desc'] + '</td><td>' + state['email'] + '</td></tr>'); 
                    }
```

Had to add this to CSS Style

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked), [type="checkbox"]:checked {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

This idea of overwriting common HTML and CSS standards to accomodate their JS is not ideal. 
I have a site stabilized with materialize, would not do it again.

Answer (score 0):

As per version 0.100.2, the solution is to add this CSS class:

```
.input-field label {
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```

Note that the structure in this version has to be:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<label for="check">label 1</label>
```

Source: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5062

Answer (score 0):

the only way I could even get the checkbox to show, and be clickable was to do this

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked), [type="checkbox"]:checked {
    position: unset;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events:all
}
```

I get no animation but to be honest I don't care I don't have any more time to waste on something the should be simple. None of the solutions above worked for me

Answer (score -2):

in version materialize 1.0

in JS 
1) find input by document.getElementById...
2) check input.checked

input.checked was be false or true

Comment: Please add a code snippet as example for the question author. Then your answer will be a lot more useful.